# A probability measure that has no point masses

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

How do we apply **3.3.2** to $X-Y$ to get the first equality of $$\lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int^T_{-T} | \phi(t)|^2 dt = P(X-Y=0) = \sum_x \mu(\{x\})^2,$$ in **3.3.3**? How does it imply that if $\varphi(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, $\mu$ has no point masses?

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\varphi$ is the characteristic function of $X$ and of $Y,$ and since those variables are independent, the characteristic function of $X - Y$ is
$$ \varphi(t) \varphi(-t) = \lvert \varphi(t)\rvert^2 .$$

If $\mu_{(X-Y)}$ is the distribution of $X-Y$ then
$\mu_{(X-Y)}(\{0\}) = P(X - Y = 0).$
Applying part (i) of $3.3.2$ to the random variable $X - Y$, 
since $e^{-it\cdot 0} = 1$ we have
$$ \mu_{X-Y}(\{0\}) 
= \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac1{2T} \int^T_{-T} \lvert \varphi(t)\rvert^2 dt.$$

Two things equal to $\mu_{X-Y}(\{0\})$ are equal to each other,
hence the first equality in $3.3.3.$

The probability that $X=Y=x$ is $(\mu(\{x\}))^2,$ hence the second equality.

If $\varphi(t)\to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ then

$$ \lim_{T\to \infty} \frac1{2T} \int^T_{-T} \lvert \varphi(t)\rvert^2 dt = 0,$$

and $\sum(\mu(\{x\}))^2 = 0$ implies $\mu(\{x\}) = 0$ for all $x.$

Answer (score 1):

$P(X=Y)=\int \int_{x=y} d\mu(x)d\mu(y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. with distribution $\mu$. Now $\int \int_{x=y} d\mu(x)d\mu(y)\int \mu\{x\} d\mu(x)$. For any probability measure $\mu$ there are at  most countable many points $x$ with $\mu \{x\}>0$. Call these $x_1,x_2,...$ in the case of $\mu$. Then the integral becomes $\sum (\mu \{x_i\})^{2}$.

The characteristic function of $X-Y$ is $|\phi|^{2}$. Hence 3.3.3. follows from 3.3.2.

If $\phi(t) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ then LHS of the equation in 3.3.3. is $0$ so $\mu \{x\}=0$ for all $x$.